# iOS SpriteKit animation does not appear

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm loading an animation using textures from a TextureAtlas.

But the animation does not appear on screen.

I appears only when I NSLog the Textures! Looks like a bug.

Does somebody made similar experience?

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasWithRetinaCorrection:spriteSheetName_];
if ([atlas.textureNames count] == 0) return;
NSArray *r = [self getSprites:WEAPON_FIREANIMATION ofDict:atlas.textureNames];
if ([r count] == 0)return;


SKSpriteNode *firstSprite = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:tFIRSTSPRITE];
[firstSprite removeActionForKey:aFIRE_ANIM];

NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
int k =0;
if (self.weaponAnimDuration == 0)
{
    k = (self.weaponShootInterval / 0.1f)/[r count];
} else
{
    k = (self.weaponAnimDuration / 0.1f)/[r count];
}
for (int i = 0; i<k; i++)
{
    for (NSString *sname in r)
    {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:sname]];
    }

}
NSLog(@"%@",walkAnimFrames);

SKAction *weaponAnim = [SKAction animateWithTextures:walkAnimFrames timePerFrame:0.1f];
[firstSprite runAction:weaponAnim withKey:aFIRE_ANIM];
```

---

```
#import "SKTextureAtlas+MySKTextureAtlas.h"
@implementation SKTextureAtlas (MySKTextureAtlas)

+(SKTextureAtlas*)atlasWithRetinaCorrection:(NSString*)name
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00)
    {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x",name];
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"atlasc"];
    if (path == Nil) return Nil;

    return [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:name];
}
```

---

```
@implementation NSArray (Tools)


-(NSArray*)animationTextureFrames
{
    NSMutableArray *rr = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *name in self)
    {
        SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:name];
        [rr addObject:tex];
    }
    return rr;
}
```

Comment: What are you using in addition to SpriteKit? When I paste your code into a new SpriteKit Game template neither atlasWithRetinaCorrection: nor animationTextureFrames are are known selectors.

Comment: atlasWithRetinaCorrection is a category which adds @2x to the parameter when we have a retina display

Comment: animationTextureFrames is another Category which filters the needed animationTexture Names

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the portion of your source code that you've posted. Since you're not posting all your relevant source code, I suspect that the issue is somewhere in these category methods you haven't shared with us, or the interaction with this posted code.

Comment: Hello Berna, the code works fine WHEN the NSLog is there. As soon as I remove the NSLog the animation does not appear.

Comment: You've made a bunch of further edits to you code, but it's still incomplete. I'm still missing much when I copy your code into a subclass of SKScene, so I'm flying somewhat blind trying to answer your question. Yet, I posted a possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the bug!

I had to preload the textures.

```
 [SKTexture preloadTextures:explosionTextures withCompletionHandler:^(void){}];
```

Comment: I found this not solve the bug completely. If preloads a lot of textures at one moment, the textures still work wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do mine, and havent had any issues yet.

```
    NSMutableArray *textures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rocket%d", i];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [textures addObject:texture];
    }

    self.rocketAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.1];
    // add animation to my sprite
    [self.projectile runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:self.rocketAnimation]];
    // add spite to screen etc...
    [self addChild:self.projectile];
```

Comment: Hi, I have also a repeatActionForever animation, there it works. The issue is in the animation which does not repeat.

Answer (score 1):

See this post, there is a bug when images have a lot of transparent space using texture atlas.

[SKTexture returns wrong size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269657/sktexture-returns-wrong-size)

Answer (score 0):

NSLog is very slow compared to most other operations. Just inserting that call adds a significant pause to the main thread of your app. I'm guessing that your texture loading is sending tasks off to the GPU. Without the NSLog call the GPU may not have enough time to complete the tasks. Maybe you can preload the textures.

Comment: I had a similar thought and I already did this. I loaded the textures in the array long before.. but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Go to you'r Project and follow these steps:- 1> Go to Build Settings, 2> Search for **Enable Texture Atlas** Generation and select **YES**