# SpriteKit animateWithTextures not work with texture atlas

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, sprite-kit

When I don't use texture atlas,everything works fine.But when I use texture atlas,animateWithTextures doesn't work and nothing appears.
Here is my code

```
SKTexture *spaceshipTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"monkey.png"];
SKSpriteNode *spaceship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:spaceshipTexture];
spaceship.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
spaceship.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
[self addChild: spaceship];

NSMutableArray *images=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:14];
for (int i=1; i<=14; i++) {
    NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dShuGuangx.png",i];
    SKTexture *tempTexture=[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:fileName];
    [images addObject:tempTexture];
}
NSLog(@"count %d",images.count);
SKAction *walkAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:images timePerFrame:0.1];
[spaceship runAction:walkAnimation];
```

Comment: did you look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159537/ios-spritekit-animation-does-not-appear and here http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases

Comment: @Smick Thank you.I found answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[SKTexture preloadTextures:images withCompletionHandler:^(void){
        [spaceship runAction:walkAnimation];
    }];
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: This helped me too. runAction() caused the app to crash with EXE_BAD_ACCESS before I preloaded the textures. Thanks!

Comment: I had a problem with `repeatActionForever:` that caused a crash and this fixed it.