# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm developing a Spritekit game.

I recevie an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` exception when touchind a node i try to run an action

This function catches the touch

```
    -(void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)location {
    SKNode *touchedNode = (SKNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
    NSLog(@"touched : %@",touchedNode.name);

    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:@"piece"]){
        Piece *piece = (Piece *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];
        if ([piece isRotated])
            [piece rotateToFront];
        else
            [piece rotateToBack];
    }
}
```

The object Piece Method `rotateBack`:

```
    -(void)rotateToBack{
    SKAction *rotationToBack = [SKAction animateWithTextures:[self animationFrames] timePerFrame:0.11];
    [self runAction:rotationToBack withKey:@"rotation-to-back"];
    [self setRotated:YES];
};
```

[self animationFrames] is a NSMutable array converted into NSArray with

```
[self setAnimationFrames:[NSArray arrayWithArray:frames]];
```

Finally frames is an the `NSMutableArray` containing some `SKTextures`

The executions brokes on animation execution.

Comment: any of these answers help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159537/ios-spritekit-animation-does-not-appear

Comment: thx but the problem is not that the animation doesn't appear, but that the application brokes

Comment: Try to define rotationToBack, piece and touchedNode as ivars. It seems that App release something before it is used.

Comment: btw you don't need to "convert" NSMutableArray to NSArray, NSMutableArray can be used just like NSArray, ie [self setAnimationFrames:frames]; is legal to do

Comment: did u get it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Piece` class

Change this line:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-1%@",[self baseImageName],imageResolution];
```

to

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-1",[self baseImageName]];
```